# Return a HTTP 200 Code to the POST client?

Tags: php, http, post

I have a server sending POST to me. I need to reply with HTTP 200 OK.
Server needs kind of like a "Go Ahead!" prompt before it executes another action.
It requires a HTTP 200 response.

**EDIT**
I've tried the header(), but the server for some reason won't read it?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the downvotes and close votes?

Comment: Some context would really help us understand exactly what it is that you are trying to do.  Could you please add some more details?

Comment: What's the SAPI? I depends on if it's CGI or not how to send the status-header.

Comment: I think it might actually be on CGI. Working on Crowdflower's API.

Answer (score 10):

The 200 code is a standard response to a successful request... Even echoing out an empty json string would result in a 200 OK status.

```
echo json_encode(array());
```

If all you want to do is signal to your client that some process was completed, you can just echo back a custom status message or even a blank object like I demonstrated above.

If you want to actually manually send the 200 header you can do so like this -

```
header('Status: 200');
```

Make sure that this header is send before you have **any** output from the server.

Comment: If I want to setup a customized return message, should I do it via the API or else where?

Comment: Actually it is: **header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');**

Comment: @Tarik - I'm not sure what version of PHP I was using when I wrote this answer - it is possible that with the newer versions this has changed. I don't work with PHP any more so I'm probably not up to date with newer changes. Feel free to edit my post to add this information if you like.

Answer (score 4):

This function call does the job:
`http_response_code(200);`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

This function call can be thrown anywhere in the server code -- the order of when this function is called does not seem to matter.

Comment: (PHP 5 >= 5.4.0, PHP 7)